# How can I get a simple Coded UI Test to run in VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests

I am attempting to run the most simple coded UI test I can think of.  I have an empty Class Library solution that I have added a coded UI Test project to.

Using the steps recorder I record the action of clicking on the Start menu (in Windows 8.1) and launching the Windows Calculator accessory program.

When I try to run this test, it fails with the following assert:

```
Test Name:  CodedUITestMethod1
Test Outcome:   Failed
Result Message: 
Test method CodedUITestProject1.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1 threw exception: 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException: The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties. Additional Details: 
TechnologyName:  'MSAA'
ControlType:  'Client'
Name:  'Start'
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

In my UIMap.uitest file, I have change the Search Configuration for the 'Start' client to Always Search, but I get the same result.

It seems strange that it can't find the Start button on the taskbar since it's always visible.

Is there anything else I can try to get this to work?

Additional Generated Code:

```
namespace CodedUITestProject1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for CodedUITest1
    /// </summary>
    [CodedUITest]
    public class CodedUITest1
    {
        public CodedUITest1()
        {
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void CodedUITestMethod1()
        {
            // To generate code for this test, select "Generate Code for Coded UI Test" from the shortcut menu and select one of the menu items.
            this.UIMap.RecordedMethod1();
        }

        #region Additional test attributes

        // You can use the following additional attributes as you write your tests:

        ////Use TestInitialize to run code before running each test 
        //[TestInitialize()]
        //public void MyTestInitialize()
        //{        
        //    // To generate code for this test, select "Generate Code for Coded UI Test" from the shortcut menu and select one of the menu items.
        //}

        ////Use TestCleanup to run code after each test has run
        //[TestCleanup()]
        //public void MyTestCleanup()
        //{        
        //    // To generate code for this test, select "Generate Code for Coded UI Test" from the shortcut menu and select one of the menu items.
        //}

        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        ///Gets or sets the test context which provides
        ///information about and functionality for the current test run.
        ///</summary>
        public TestContext TestContext
        {
            get
            {
                return testContextInstance;
            }
            set
            {
                testContextInstance = value;
            }
        }
        private TestContext testContextInstance;

        public UIMap UIMap
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.map == null))
                {
                    this.map = new UIMap();
                }

                return this.map;
            }
        }

        private UIMap map;
    }
}

namespace CodedUITestProject1
{
    using System;
    using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.WinControls;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using Keyboard = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Keyboard;
    using Mouse = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse;
    using MouseButtons = System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons;


    [GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "14.0.23107.0")]
    public partial class UIMap
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// RecordedMethod1
        /// </summary>
        public void RecordedMethod1()
        {
            #region Variable Declarations
            WinClient uIStartClient = this.UIItemWindow.UIStartClient;
            WinControl uILogoImage = this.UIStartmenuWindow.UICalculatorListItem.UILogoImage;
            WinButton uIItem5Button = this.UICalculatorWindow.UIItemWindow.UIItem5Button;
            WinButton uIMultiplyButton = this.UICalculatorWindow.UIItemWindow1.UIMultiplyButton;
            WinButton uIItem6Button = this.UICalculatorWindow.UIItemWindow2.UIItem6Button;
            WinButton uIEqualsButton = this.UICalculatorWindow.UIItemWindow3.UIEqualsButton;
            #endregion

            // Click 'Start' client
            Mouse.Click(uIStartClient, new Point(7, 1572));

            // Click 'Logo' image
            Mouse.Click(uILogoImage, new Point(30, 12));

            // Click '5' button
            Mouse.Click(uIItem5Button, new Point(13, 12));

            // Click 'Multiply' button
            Mouse.Click(uIMultiplyButton, new Point(21, 12));

            // Click '6' button
            Mouse.Click(uIItem6Button, new Point(16, 15));

            // Click 'Equals' button
            Mouse.Click(uIEqualsButton, new Point(19, 26));
        }

        #region Properties
        public UIItemWindow UIItemWindow
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.mUIItemWindow == null))
                {
                    this.mUIItemWindow = new UIItemWindow();
                }
                return this.mUIItemWindow;
            }
        }

        public UIStartmenuWindow UIStartmenuWindow
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.mUIStartmenuWindow == null))
                {
                    this.mUIStartmenuWindow = new UIStartmenuWindow();
                }
                return this.mUIStartmenuWindow;
            }
        }

        public UICalculatorWindow UICalculatorWindow
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.mUICalculatorWindow == null))
                {
                    this.mUICalculatorWindow = new UICalculatorWindow();
                }
                return this.mUICalculatorWindow;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Fields
        private UIItemWindow mUIItemWindow;

        private UIStartmenuWindow mUIStartmenuWindow;

        private UICalculatorWindow mUICalculatorWindow;
        #endregion
    }

    [GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "14.0.23107.0")]
    public class UIItemWindow : WinWindow
    {

        public UIItemWindow()
        {
            #region Search Criteria
            this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.AccessibleName] = "Desktop";
            this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "#32769";
            #endregion
        }

        #region Properties
        public WinClient UIStartClient
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.mUIStartClient == null))
                {
                    this.mUIStartClient = new WinClient(this);
                    #region Search Criteria
                    this.mUIStartClient.SearchProperties[WinControl.PropertyNames.Name] = "Start";
                    this.mUIStartClient.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);
                    this.mUIStartClient.SearchConfigurations.Remove(SearchConfiguration.VisibleOnly);
                    #endregion
                }
                return this.mUIStartClient;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Fields
        private WinClient mUIStartClient;
        #endregion
    }

    [GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "14.0.23107.0")]
    public class UIStartmenuWindow : WinWindow
    {

        public UIStartmenuWindow()
        {
            #region Search Criteria
            this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "Start menu";
            this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "ImmersiveLauncher";
            this.WindowTitles.Add("Start menu");
            #endregion
        }

        #region Properties
        public UICalculatorListItem UICalculatorListItem
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.mUICalculatorListItem == null))
                {
                    this.mUICalculatorListItem = new UICalculatorListItem(this);
                }
                return this.mUICalculatorListItem;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Fields
        private UICalculatorListItem mUICalculatorListItem;
        #endregion
    }

    [GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "14.0.23107.0")]
    public class UICalculatorListItem : WinListItem
    {

        public UICalculatorListItem(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) : 
                base(searchLimitContainer)
        {
            #region Search Criteria
            this.SearchProperties[WinListItem.PropertyNames.Name] = "Calculator";
            this.WindowTitles.Add("Start menu");
            #endregion
        }

        #region Properties
        public WinControl UILogoImage
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.mUILogoImage == null))
                {
                    this.mUILogoImage = new WinControl(this);
                    #region Search Criteria
                    this.mUILogoImage.SearchProperties[UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name] = "Logo";
                    this.mUILogoImage.SearchProperties[UITestControl.PropertyNames.ControlType] = "Image";
                    this.mUILogoImage.WindowTitles.Add("Start menu");
                    #endregion
                }
                return this.mUILogoImage;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Fields
        private WinControl mUILogoImage;
        #endregion
    }

    [GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "14.0.23107.0")]
    public class UICalculatorWindow : WinWindow
    {

        public UICalculatorWindow()
        {
            #region Search Criteria
            this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "Calculator";
            this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "CalcFrame";
            this.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator");
            #endregion
        }

        #region Properties
        public UIItemWindow1 UIItemWindow
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.mUIItemWindow == null))
                {
                    this.mUIItemWindow = new UIItemWindow1(this);
                }
                return this.mUIItemWindow;
            }
        }

        public UIItemWindow11 UIItemWindow1
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.mUIItemWindow1 == null))
                {
                    this.mUIItemWindow1 = new UIItemWindow11(this);
                }
                return this.mUIItemWindow1;
            }
        }

        public UIItemWindow2 UIItemWindow2
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.mUIItemWindow2 == null))
                {
                    this.mUIItemWindow2 = new UIItemWindow2(this);
                }
                return this.mUIItemWindow2;
            }
        }

        public UIItemWindow3 UIItemWindow3
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.mUIItemWindow3 == null))
                {
                    this.mUIItemWindow3 = new UIItemWindow3(this);
                }
                return this.mUIItemWindow3;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Fields
        private UIItemWindow1 mUIItemWindow;

        private UIItemWindow11 mUIItemWindow1;

        private UIItemWindow2 mUIItemWindow2;

        private UIItemWindow3 mUIItemWindow3;
        #endregion
    }

    [GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "14.0.23107.0")]
    public class UIItemWindow1 : WinWindow
    {

        public UIItemWindow1(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) : 
                base(searchLimitContainer)
        {
            #region Search Criteria
            this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlId] = "135";
            this.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator");
            #endregion
        }

        #region Properties
        public WinButton UIItem5Button
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.mUIItem5Button == null))
                {
                    this.mUIItem5Button = new WinButton(this);
                    #region Search Criteria
                    this.mUIItem5Button.SearchProperties[WinButton.PropertyNames.Name] = "5";
                    this.mUIItem5Button.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator");
                    #endregion
                }
                return this.mUIItem5Button;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Fields
        private WinButton mUIItem5Button;
        #endregion
    }

    [GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "14.0.23107.0")]
    public class UIItemWindow11 : WinWindow
    {

        public UIItemWindow11(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) : 
                base(searchLimitContainer)
        {
            #region Search Criteria
            this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlId] = "92";
            this.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator");
            #endregion
        }

        #region Properties
        public WinButton UIMultiplyButton
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.mUIMultiplyButton == null))
                {
                    this.mUIMultiplyButton = new WinButton(this);
                    #region Search Criteria
                    this.mUIMultiplyButton.SearchProperties[WinButton.PropertyNames.Name] = "Multiply";
                    this.mUIMultiplyButton.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator");
                    #endregion
                }
                return this.mUIMultiplyButton;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Fields
        private WinButton mUIMultiplyButton;
        #endregion
    }

    [GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "14.0.23107.0")]
    public class UIItemWindow2 : WinWindow
    {

        public UIItemWindow2(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) : 
                base(searchLimitContainer)
        {
            #region Search Criteria
            this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlId] = "136";
            this.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator");
            #endregion
        }

        #region Properties
        public WinButton UIItem6Button
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.mUIItem6Button == null))
                {
                    this.mUIItem6Button = new WinButton(this);
                    #region Search Criteria
                    this.mUIItem6Button.SearchProperties[WinButton.PropertyNames.Name] = "6";
                    this.mUIItem6Button.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator");
                    #endregion
                }
                return this.mUIItem6Button;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Fields
        private WinButton mUIItem6Button;
        #endregion
    }

    [GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "14.0.23107.0")]
    public class UIItemWindow3 : WinWindow
    {

        public UIItemWindow3(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) : 
                base(searchLimitContainer)
        {
            #region Search Criteria
            this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlId] = "121";
            this.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator");
            #endregion
        }

        #region Properties
        public WinButton UIEqualsButton
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.mUIEqualsButton == null))
                {
                    this.mUIEqualsButton = new WinButton(this);
                    #region Search Criteria
                    this.mUIEqualsButton.SearchProperties[WinButton.PropertyNames.Name] = "Equals";
                    this.mUIEqualsButton.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator");
                    #endregion
                }
                return this.mUIEqualsButton;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Fields
        private WinButton mUIEqualsButton;
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: please include the code that the UI map generated.  record and play can capture properties which are too specific for repeatable searching.

Comment: Added code from CodedUITest1.cs and UIMap.Designer.CS

Comment: Interesting.  If you are running on the same machine with same configuration, seems correct.  The Point seems strange though Point(7, 1572) would be second monitor or something.

You can step thru the code and using the watch window / immediate window, see if the correct desktop is being found by using DrawHighlight()

Comment: At which step is it failing?

Comment: I am running on the same machine with same configuration.  I have 3 monitors and when I do the recording, I am on the center monitor.  It is failing on the very first step (clicking on the start button).  Basically none of the steps run.  I'll try stepping through to see if it is finding the right desktop.

Comment: I'm still not sure why this doesn't work.  However, I tried to replicate the problem using Visual Studio 2015 on a Windows 7 x64 installation and the test ran fine.  Then, on the Windows 8.1 installation, rather than starting the program from the start menu, I created a shortcut to it on the desktop and launched it from the shortcut.  The test was also successful doing it this way.  Maybe the operating system has something to do with it.